# Is there a way to completely stop energy losses due to thermal radiation?

Tags: energy-conservation, thermal-radiation

If all bodies emit thermal radiation, does it mean that it's impossible to build something that can retain all of its energy - and last indefinitely? i.e. is everything in our world, including a dynamic, living system that can self-repair, eventually gonna collapse?

OR - there is something in Thermodynamics similar to Superconductivity in Electromagnetism that would help prevent this?

OR if there is no such effect, is there, even theoretically, a way to mitigate the effects? I can only think of creating new energy within a system faster than the system can lose it due to thermal radiation, but doesn't this violate conservation law(s)?

Comment: While all objects with a temperature above absolute zero emit thermal radiation, not all objects gain or lose energy due to emitting thermal radiation. That requires a difference in temperature between an object and the other objects in its environment.

Comment: @BobD I'm not sure I understand. You're saying that an object can emit photons that carry no energy? And that an object in a vacuum will lose no energy despite emitting thermal radiation?

Comment: No. What I am saying is if the radiating object and its surroundings are in thermal equilibrium (i.e. at the same temperature) the amount of energy emitted by the object equals the amount of energy received by the object.

Comment: @BobD I am sorry, I'm still having difficulties understanding this. Let's imagine an object drifting in the vacuum of space. Will it eventually cool down to temperatures near absolute zero if there was: a) perfect vacuum b) real vacuum where said object would periodically collide with atoms/electrons in the intergalactic space?

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with mine. An example of mine is an object of temperature T suspended in a complete  enclosure also of temperature T.  There will be no net heat transfer by radiation between the object and the enclosure. Thus the object will neither gain nor lose energy.

Answer (score 0):

there is no thermodynamic equivalent to superconductivity. If there are temperature differences, there will be heat transfer. But there are clever ways to *minimize* heat loss by blocking a hot object's ability to radiate and absorb infrared radiation. The most common of these is a *thermos bottle*, which envelops a hot container with a vacuum and whose walls are finished with a mirror coating. the vacuum halts conduction and the mirrored walls halt absorption. This will keep a quart of coffee hot for a day, but eventually the heat will slowly leak out.